# Untar a file with !tar -xzvf a 100GB file

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory, tar

I'm trying to untar a dataset which is 100GB using !tar -xzvf. I executed the command yesterday on colab pro+ (I'm using the dataset for ML) yesterday, but the file is still untarring. Is there any other way to untar the file in order to save time?

I need to then run a python script to read from the json of the folders within.

Comment: use 7 zip. is faster. Also check if you can read the file with python without decompressing it

Comment: How much space do you have in Google Colab? You can do `!df -h` to get a view.

Comment: If it fits in your workflow with colab, maybe you could skip extracting the tar and access it from Python with [ratarmountcore](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount/tree/master/core) or mount it via FUSE with [ratarmount](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount).